# asp.NET applying paging with Skip and Take on gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, paging

What I want to have is 5 results in each 3 pages.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that the grid view handles paging without any code that would utilize skip and take.  What you're doing is attempting to do in memory paging, the grid view already does this.  Anyhow as an exercise you would want

```
const int PageSize = 5
int pageNumber = 3;
int skip = (pageNumber - 1)*PageSize;

IEnumerable<DataRow> MyDataPage = dt.AsEnumerable().Skip(skip).Take(PageSize);
```

I should also add that you're playing with a technology stack within .NET that is only really present for legacy support.  Most who once upon a time might have used DataSets and DataTables are now using Entity Framework and LINQ.  Plus classic ASP.NET pages aren't going to be the choice for developing web forms any more.  You might be better off studying MVC or Angular JS and Web API

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I use MVC in my  day job with Spring Framework but I wanted to take things slow in my first day with .net . How can I make grid view handle paging? Adding PageSize="5" does not solve the problem.

Comment: Try following this article.... https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/816953/How-To-Implement-Paging-in-GridView-Control-in-ASP.  Studying classic ASP.NET pages isn't what I'd call "taking things slow", its just very different, and dated, it's a 16 years old, very high level development sdk for building web applications.  One of the main complaints with this framework, is that it's too black box and hides too much.   Other than broad architectural concepts, there's very little you'll be able to take away from it that will help you with more modern frameworks and approaches

Answer (score 0):

```
Make sure these two fields are sent as part of HttpRequest from client 
/// <summary>
    /// Number of records that should be shown in table
    /// </summary>
    public int DisplayLength { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// First record that should be shown(used for paging)
    /// </summary>
    public int DisplayStart { get; set; }

//Server side code
GetData(){

             Members.Skip(param.DisplayStart)  
             .Take(param.DisplayLength); 
}
```